# Syntax error when calling stored procedure inside stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax-error

I'm trying to call a stored procedure inside another stored procedure.

I'm getting a syntax error in the statement where main procedure calls the child procedure.

here is my query

```
DROP  PROCEDURE GetAllProducts;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts()
BEGIN

DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE myName varchar(60);
DEClARE myCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT Name FROM Test;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
FOR NOT FOUND SET finished =1 ;



OPEN myCursor;

get_email: LOOP
FETCH myCursor INTO myName;
IF finished = 1 THEN
 LEAVE get_email;
END IF;

-- Line which shows a syntax error
EXEC UpdateProdcut myName;

END LOOP get_email;




CLOSE myCursor;
DEALLOCATE myCursor;


END //
DELIMITER ;
```

This is the error message

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'UpdateProdcut myName OUTPUT;
```

mysql version is 5.5.54

any idea about this ?

Thanks.

Comment: You aren't CALLing it. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/call.html

Comment: thanx.
I changed it call and now it's working.

btw I thought it's using EXECUTE to call it

Comment: SQLSERVER exec stored procedure mysql execute is for executing prepared statements (ie dynamic sql) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/execute.html

Comment: thanx again for pointing me the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CALL` instead:

```
call UpdateProdcut(myName);
```

`execute` is used for prepared statements.

Ref:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/call.html